# Using Hibernate HQL Named Queries in Grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm, named-query

Is there a way to use Hibernate Named Queries in Grails, using HQL?

I've been reading about them in the [Harnessing Hibernate book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517724.do), and wondered if there was a way to use them in Grails.

Named queries are included, along with the class mappings, in a `<class-name>.hbm.xml` mapping files like so:

```
<query name="com.oreilly.hh.tracksNoLongerThan">
   <![CDATA[
         from Track as track
           where track.playTime <= :length
     ]>
</query>
```

Now I'm certain that an `<class-name>.hbm.xml` *hibernate mapping file* can be included and integrated into the Grails GORM configuration as [it is stated here](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/hibernate.html#usingHibernateXMLMappingFiles) that the `hibernate.cfg.xml` which includes the *hibernate mapping file* can used within Grails.

In old Hibernate and Java it can be accessed this way:

```
    ...
Query query = session.getNamedQuery(
                "com.oreilly.hh.tracksNoLongerThan");

query.setTime("length", length);
return query.list();
    ...
```

But, how can one access these HQL named queries from Grails?

The reason I ask is I'd like to be able to take a legacy database and map it to some objects for use in Grails, and store the named queries along with the mappings.

Comment: P.S. I've already seen the reference to named queries in the Grails docs...http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is with the `withSession` method on any domain class, e.g.

```
SomeDomainClass.withSession { session ->
   Query query = session.getNamedQuery('com.oreilly.hh.tracksNoLongerThan')
   query.setTime 'length', length
   query.list()
}
```

or more compactly using method chaining:

```
SomeDomainClass.withSession { session ->
   session.getNamedQuery('com.oreilly.hh.tracksNoLongerThan')
      .setTime('length', length)
      .list()
}
```