# how to create custom queries in grails domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

Is there a way to create a query in a grails domain that always returns the records that have a specific criteria?

For example:

```
Class Person {

  String firstname
  String lastname
}
```

Now instead of saying `Person.findByFirstname("Bart")` all over the codebase is there anything I can do inside the `Person` domain class so that I can simply say something like `Person.bart`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `namedQueries` support available within Grails/GORM should meet this need: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html

```
   static namedQueries = {
       firstNameBart {
           eq 'firstname', 'Bart'
       }
   }
```

Then used in this way:

```
def barts = Person.firstNameBart.list()
```

Comment: but my query is in hql. Can I have hql inside namedqueries?

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe `namedQueries` supports criteria builder only. If you have your HQL in an external `hbm.xml` file, you can use this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824465/using-hibernate-hql-named-queries-in-grails