# How can I write a "not exists" query in grails named queries?

Tags: hibernate, grails

How can I write a "not exists" query in hibernate criteria or named queries? I am trying to get a named query not exists query which returns the same results as this Oracle SQL query:

```
select *
from SCHOOL a
where not exists (select 1
from STUDENT b
where B.SCHOOL_ID=a.id
and B.STATUS_ID not in (0,1,2,3,4))
```

Comment: show what you have tried..

Comment: I have tried HQL. I want to implement it in named queries since I'll be using it a lot in my application. I did not want to clutter the application with Oracle SQL syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sqlRestriction`. This will be injected directly in the final query, so you need to use the database column names.

```
School.createCriteria().list {
  sqlRestriction(" not exists(select 1 from student s where s.school_id = this_.id and ...)")
}
```

Comment: isn't the sqlRestriction make the application dependent to the under lining database engine. Is there a library extending the HibernateCriteriaBuilder?

Comment: You meant **not** exists I guess.

Comment: @user2679352 Yes, but this query seems pretty standard to me. If you don't use database functions you're good to go. Another solution is to use HQL like JB answers you.

Comment: How did you know to use `this_` for the School table. Is this mentioned somewhere in hibernate docs?

Comment: @mowwwalker I looked at the generated query

Answer (score 2):

In HQL:

```
select s from School s where not exists (
    select st.id from Student st 
    where st.school = s 
    and st.statusId not in (0,1,2,3,4))
```

Comment: Is there a way to put the HQL in a named query?

Comment: That's the principle of a named query: it's an HQL query with a name. I don't get your question.

Comment: When implementing static namedQueries = { mynamedquery {}} on the domain object. it expect a HibernateCriteriaBuilder definition. Is there a way to write HQL for HibernateCriteriaBuilder?

Comment: In my experience, forget about not using HQL. It can do things much easier than criteria queries. That is just my 2c though.

Comment: @user2679352 You are not getting the point. Criteria/NamedQuery ultimately converts to an HQL query while execution. You can use the above HQL directly. Moreover, you can create a static method/closure inside the domain class which uses this query to give you results, and use it the way you use dynamic finders.

Comment: OK. Now I understand. Grails has it own notion of named queries which are not the same as Hibernate named queries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824465/using-hibernate-hql-named-queries-in-grails